Does Windows multi boot share BitLocker key from the TPM?
I want to use an application that requires kernel access and can't be run on a VM, but I want to isolate it from my day-to-day environment, without buying a whole new PC for it.
I thought about using BitLocker on my day-to-day windows partition and run the potentially compromising app on a second partition so it would not be able to access my data.
Last time I had win multi boot the 2 versions recognized one another and asked me which one to run on startup, so I worry, will the 2 Windows installations share the BitLocker key if I use my MOBO's virtual tpm for the key?
Should I worry about BitLocker going haywire from switching between win versions and locking my encrypted data forever?

There have been numerous questions on this site about BitLocker failure, with the general answer being, "All data is lost." Before making any major change, make a complete drive image.  Then you can test various scenarios, such as running from partitions on the internal drive, or putting the app on a bootable external SSD, or encrypting a whole partition or just part of it, and whether to use BitLocker or another app, such as VeraCrypt.

No, only one key can be store and the same key cannot be used for both instances


will the 2 Windows installations share the BitLocker key if I use my MOBO's virtual tpm for the key?

BitLocker doesn't use the TPM for the key, it uses the TPM to protect the key. But although the keys are different, the conditions it sets up for having the TPM release the key are going to be the same (although the use of the BIOS boot menu may differentiate them). It's approximately the same as having two disks use the same passphrase.
The TPM is provisioned by Windows on first boot, but that shouldn't cause problems, as it deliberately throws away the 'owner password' during the process so there's nothing that makes the TPM unusable with a dualboot OS – only individual items are bound in some way or another – although I'd still keep the BitLocker recovery keys handy just in case.

Should I worry about BitLocker going haywire from switching between win versions and locking my encrypted data forever?

You get the 'Recovery Key' from BitLocker specifically to avoid that. It decrypts a separate copy of the volume key without relying on the TPM.

No, only one key can be store and the same key cannot be used for both instances

It can. The TPM does not store BitLocker keys directly; it stores only a "Storage Root Key" (of which a TPMv2 can fit more than one, but that's rarely done), which is provisioned in a way that it can be used by any OS for any purpose.
